# Как создать приложение с Google Maps работающее в оффлайн-режиме?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, геолокация

Необходимо создать приложение для Android с Google Maps в котором определяются координаты и высота над уровнем моря для заданной точки, но в offline-режиме.

Как это лучше сделать и реально ли вообще?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Comment: Google Maps не даёт свой движок в offline. Как вы собираетесь его использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Использовать связку из подругженной заранее части карты/карт (города, к примеру, и высот соотвествующих) и GPS.